# Erro install PECL ID3 tag support module for PHP

Tags: installation, php, extension

I'm trying unsuccessfully to install [id3](http://pecl.php.net/package/id3) from PECL ([tutorial](https://www.siamnet.org/Wiki/Ubuntu-Php-HowToInstallId3SupportInPhp)). So, I did:

```
mkdir id3tmp
cd id3tmp
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/id3-0.2.tgz
tar -zxvf id3-0.2.tgz
pecl build
```

And here, I got the error:

```
error: initializer element is not computable at load time 
error: (near initialization for 'id3_functions[8]')
```

From google for this error I got very little, nothing significant.

How can I solve this error ? Or, How to successfully install id3 from PECL on Ubuntu ?

Comment: **Please help me, I need to install PECL using Unix** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362340/how-to-install-php-trader-pecl-using-unix?r=SearchResults&s=11|50.0164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because I had PHP 5.4 version ([bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64000&edit=1))

I downgrade my PHP version to 5.3 and now works.

Comment: There's no bug in PHP 5.4. The references ID3 PECL module is unmaintained and you should not be using it.  Who know how many security bugs are in the code...

Comment: I'm not saying that there was a bug in PHP :) just refer to more info. And yes, No one should use it.

Answer (score 1):

The id3 module was last updated in 2004.  The PHP/Zend API has changed several times from that date, so the module cannot be used with most recent PHP.

You can either fix it yourself, ask the author, or hire somebody to do it for you.

However I would suggest to just use some external tool to read/write ID3 tags from PHP using the system/exec/...

Comment: yes, very old. Now i use: http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ID3v2